# Android Studio is not capturing error log when errors/exceptions thrown from coroutines/scope funtions only for Xiaomi device

Tags: android, android-studio, logcat

I have tried multiple things but still not able to find the issue why Logcat is not capturing/showing errors/exceptions for xiaomi device. Now the problem is, to debug the issue I need to run application code on any other device then logcat shows the correct error then only I am able to fix issue.